# The Wordpress Search.php pagination returns a 404 on page 2, when only 1 result is left

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm working on a search.php page in Wordpress, and have used the following code to alter the query:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }


$args = array(
  's'             => get_search_query(true),
  'showposts'     => '8',
  'paged'         => $paged
);

$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It works fine when there are over 10 results, but if there are 9 results, when you click to the second page, it gives a 404 error.

I've tried resetting the permalinks, but no dice. The permalink link is:

```
site.com/page/2/?s=prep+production
```

Is there something I'm missing to get the that 9th one to show up?

Comment: Double (triple!) check that you don't have any pages, posts, media, etc. with a slug of "page".

Comment: So I double-checked this, but I don't think it's the issue; the pagination works for items that have more than 10 results, just not for results that only have 1 more. I'm thinking possibly a offset issue?